# help in writing equation

Tags: equations

i would like to compile the below equation...whenever i compile, i get an error saying missing `$ inserted and missing } inserted`. Where do i rectify it. I am using double column ieee conference and the equation number goes out of the column. Please help

```
\begin{equation}
\lefteqn{P_{n_i}(e,(t+1)) = p_{n_i}(e,t)+\eta_{n_i}[\bar{U}_{n_i}(e)-\bar{U}_{n_i}]p_{n_i}(e,t)} \label{eq:overall_pd}
```

Comment: Do you have an `\end{equation}`, not shown in your example?  Also, what is `\lefteqn`?  I don't recognize the syntax.  In general, it helps to provide a full minimum working example, starting with `\documentclass` to avoid guesswork.

Comment: yes i have \end{equation}

Comment: @campa: And `eqnarray` is horrible too (and outdated) ;-)

Comment: Additionally I would change the brackets `[...]` to `\left[...\right]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really clear, what you want to do as you have not given us an MWE. But here is how I would typeset this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{equation}\label{eq:overall_pd}
P_{n_i}\bigl(e,(t+1)\bigr) = p_{n_i}(e,t) +\eta_{n_i}\bigl[\bar{U}_{n_i}(e) -\bar{U}_{n_i}\bigr]p_{n_i}(e,t)
\end{equation}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]